# how to use flow on network data?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Does flow check runtime type error?

Lets say I have react component that displayes userName and Icon from user Object.
user object is

```
type User: {|
    name: string,
    icon: { url: string }
  |},
```

without flow I write this.

```
const MyIcon = ({user}) => {
  const name = user.name || ''
  const icon = user.icon || {}
  const url = icon.url || ''

  return <Image src={url}>
}

// other component
<MyIcon user={{}}
```

this doen not give me error. But this does not fail me. Default values.

But with flow I can do this

```
type User = {|
    name: string,
    icon: { url: string }
  |}

const MyIcon = ({user}: {user: User}) => {
  return <Image src={url}>
}

// other component
<MyIcon user={{}}
```

It gives me nice error.

But my app is getting user data from network. Network request can be null. Or not null just wrong structured object. Like this.

```
const user = await getUserFromNetwork() 
// what if user={name: { q: 1 }, icon: null}
```

Now my flow code contains runtime error. I am forced to write my code like this again.

```
type User = {|
    name: string,
    icon: { url: string }
  |}

const MyIcon = ({user}: {user: User}) => {
  const name = user.name || ''
  const icon = user.icon || {}
  const url = icon.url || ''
  return <Image src={url}>
}

// other component
const user = await getUserFromNetwork() 
// what if user={name: { q: 1 }, icon: null}
<MyIcon user={user}
```

So its just extra work compared to the non flow version, What is the point of using Flow?

Even if I use React's defaultProps `user={name: { q: 1 }, icon: null}` results with error.

Am i missing something?. Or flow is just for source code data checking and  using it on network data is wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow only check if the usage of your code is correct (according to the provided types).
It can't be certain that network-data is in the correct type, but it assumes so if you add a type.

In your case, you should perform the extra checks so you're sure it has the correct type.
If not, you can add default-values for instance.